# Simple EEG circuit is not working

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, analog, instrumentation-amplifier, eeg

My simple EEG circuit is not working. For a simple test I built my EEG circuit on a breadboard and wanted to see if it works before adding filters and moving it to perfboard. I used an AD620AN and a TL082CN.

[image: Schematic]

The gain is 50 * 50 * 50 = 125000. As alpha and beta wave amplitudes have a range of about from 10 uV to 40 uV, output should has a range of about from ±1.25V to ±5V.

Purple wires are connections to electrodes. There is also a voltage divider (R1 = 2k2 ohm and R2 = 1k ohm) connected to OUT/2 to decrease 0-18V to 0-5V. Voltage divider output is connected to an Arduino.

But the circuit is not working. There isn't even some noise on the output. Arduino is reading about 380 but no / very little movement. I even changed the AD620 and TL082 with new ones but it didn't work also.

It is really strange that this simple circuit doesn't work.

What can be "the problem"? I'm out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your schematic doesn't show connection to an Arduino. What node is OUT?

Comment: @vofa Output node is a voltage divider connected to OUT/2 that also not shown in the schematic.

Comment: The biggest "problem" of all budding designers is "Lack of design Specs" in this case Transfer function Passband Gain and Stop Band Attenuation and max Galvanic Skin response from electrodes (Vdc)  ( as a minimum) then add CMRR or acceptance criteria for SNR

Comment: Did you connect the inputs to anything? or even bother to measure every pin Vdc for proper range?

Answer (score 5):

For reference and to protect against future edits, here is the schematic being discussed:

[image]

There are several issues:

Draw opamps like opamps!  This is very annoying to look at since I can't "see" the circuit without mentally deciphering the blocks.  I'm guessing the AD620 thing is some kind of amplifier, and I know a TL082 is.

There are no bypass capacitors on the power and ground inputs to the amplifiers.  There is no point getting into this any further until that is fixed.

Picking up tiny signals from the body requires careful analog design.  One problem is the huge common mode noise, since your body picks up stray signals from the environment.  You have to consider both pickup of radio stations, and capacitive pickup from nearby power wiring.

This is usually dealt with by having a reference electrode that the other signals are interpreted relative to.  For a EKG, for example, a connection to the right leg is typical for this.

Answer (score 2):

You have not AC coupled your circuit.

Your electrodes will have a DC offset to them.  Gaining up the offset by 125000 will almost certainly rail your amplifier.  To correct the problem, place a capacitor in series with each of R1, R2, and R5.  The size of the capacitor should be such that the cutoff frequency is below the lowest frequency of interest to you.

Comment: Why should I AC-couple my circuit? Won't DC offsets be substracted / removed as non inverting inputs are connected to the ground?

Comment: Each electrode will have a different offset, and the difference between the offsets will be amplified by the gain of the amplifier.